# Matlab concatenation

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have a problem with concatenation 2 matrices on this way:

```
A = [1;3;5;7;9];
B = [2;4;6;8;10];
```

I need to matrix `C = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10];`

I tried many diffrent aproaches,  but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
reshape([A'; B'], 1, 10);
```

The `[A'; B']` gives you:

```
 1     3     5     7     9
 2     4     6     8    10
```

and the `reshape` command does a column-wise reshaping into `1` row and `10` columns

Comment: `[A', B']` does the job.

Comment: @AnderBiguri no it does not. `[A' B']` results in: `[1     3     5     7     9     2     4     6     8    10]`

Comment: I misunderstood the question! you are completely right.